# English-language art/design schools in European Union

Tags: eu-citizens, study

My friend is a citizen of a country that is part of the European Union (Finland). She is interested in studying arts abroad. Painting would be the first option, but she is also interested in photography and design. I'm asking for help to find a possible school for her.

We've been Googling a lot for schools in Europe, but the first problem is that most of them require the applicant to have a working knowledge of the local language. For example, most schools in Germany that we've found have this requirement.

Second problem is funding. In many countries, school fees are high (thousands of euros per semester). Then there are some countries that at least partially provide free education for citizens of other EU countries (apparently Scotland has such a system).

As I mentioned, extensive Googling for possible countries/schools has not been of help. We've looked into schools in Baltic countries, Nordic countries, Germany and Eastern Europe. Can anybody recommend any schools that would meet these requirements? **So to summarize: The country/school should be located in Europe, it should not require previous knowledge of the local language, and should have low studying fees.** If the question is too broad as it is, I would be glad to provide additional details. Thank you!

Comment: There is no question here. None.

Comment: @fkraiem True, I added one line to make it explicit. I still don't think a downvote was necessary as what I'm asking was still quite obvious if you read my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gerrit Rietveld Academie](https://rietveldacademie.nl/) is an option; there is an [English language proficiency requirement](https://rietveldacademie.nl/en/page/518/admissions-international-students).  In general, international academic programs in the Netherlands operate in English.